# Cloudwatch permissions to running instance with no IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been reading up on configuring cloudwatch log service, however [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) say that you must attatch a permission to the IAM role of your instance. If I already have an instance running that doesn't have an IAM role attached, what options do I have as far as configuring this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone your current instance into a new EC2 instance that has an IAM instance profile (role) assigned.

1. Stop your EC2 instance.
2. Create an AMI image of your EC2 instance.
3. Launch a new EC2 instance from your AMI image, this time assigning an IAM role.

Answer (score 1):

If the instance was not launched without an IAM role, then:

1. Create a policy (not an inline policy) as specified in the document
2. Add a test IAM user and attach the policy to the test_user
3. From the IAM dashboard, download or copy the test_user security credentials (key and secret)
4. On your instance,  use `aws configure` and configure the credentials by using the key and secret

It may look complicated but it is not.